# Desempilhar não pode retornar um elemento vazio?

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

Código retirado de uma apostila de Estrutura de Dados.

```
public class PilhaContig {
        private Item [] info;
        private int topo;

        public PilhaContig(int qte){
            this.topo = 0;
            this.info = new Item [qte];
        }
        public Item getInfo(){
            return this.info[this.topo-1];
        }
        public int getTopo(){
            return this.topo;
        }
        public boolean eVazia(){
            return (this.topo == 0);
        }
        public boolean eCheia(){
            return (this.topo == this.info.length);
        }
        public boolean empilhar (Item elem){
            if (this.eCheia()) 
                return false;
            else {
                this.info[this.topo]= elem;
                this.topo++;
                return true;
            }   
        }
        public Item desempilhar(){
            if (this.eVazia())
                return null;
            else{
                this.topo--;
                return this.info[this.topo];
            }
        }
```

Na classe pilha a variável topo aponta para o espaço de memória vazio acima do ultimo item inserido na pilha. Se eu desempilhar o ultimo item com esse método (diminuindo 1 na variável topo `this.topo--;` e retornando o vetor `info` com o *index* no topo diminuído `return this.info[this.topo];`) eu não iria acabar retornando o último item da pilha em vez de desempilhar esse item?

Comment: Não entendi qual sua dúvida

Comment: Se o topo aponta para o espaço vazio acima do último item da pilha, eu diminuindo o topo -1, não vou acabar retornando o último espaço vazio em vez de desempilhar 1 item?

Comment: O que é espaço vazio acima do último item?

Comment: O espaço de memória, em cima do último item da pilha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É uma questão lógica, basta ler o que você escreveu.

O ponteiro `topo` está sempre apontando para a próxima posição livre na pilha. Quando você faz o `-1` ele passa apontar para o último item e o retorna. A partir daí esse item passar ser desconsiderado porque logo a seguir esse número não é mais acessível pelo algoritmo escrito a não ser para escrever um novo item ali em cima (função `empilhar()`).

Comment: Entendi. Eu estava achando que após eu usar esse método, teria que atribuir o valor 0 ou null para a variável topo, mas como você disse o número não fica mais acessível e é desconsiderado. Ficou claro, obrigado!